# React route with parameters not reachable through URL with browserRouter

Tags: reactjs, parameters, routes, react-router, blogs

So, I'm trying to create a blog page listing.

If someone clicks a particular blog changing the route to `/title/the-title-of-the-blog`, and in the route file I have route as,

```
<Route path='/title/:title' component={BlogMicroSite}/>
```

it's working fine. But, If I try reaching out `/title/some-tile-of-blog` directly it's not working. One solution is to use `HashRouter` but it adds a `#` to URL which is not SEO friendly at all. Please Help me with some solution without `#` or how I can remove `#` in the URL.

Comment: `But, If I try reaching out /title/some-tile-of-blog directly it's not working.` what you mean by direct ?

Comment: Not working means, it is not rendering the expected content at all? Or are you getting any error?

Comment: it's not rendering anything at all. The same problem is faced by many others